# permission for exported service in android

Tags: android, service, permissions

I installed the new android ADT and now I see warnings about exported services defined in the AndroidManifest that do not require a permission. 
The problem is that the services are related with the sync adapter. In the SampleSyncAdaapter there are no required permissions either but I do not see that warning.

Which permission should I define for the sync adapter?

I have the same problem for the service that handles CLEAR_MISSED_CALLS.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that warning because you are exporting the service with no permission restrictions. In your `<service>` declaration, make the permission `android:permission="your.app.name"`.
Example:
`<service android:name=".ClassName" android:permission="your.app.name"></service>`

For a more detailed explanation, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558334/get-rid-of-exported-service-does-not-require-permission-warning#answer-11562025).